# After installing Gnome, icons in Unity changes

Tags: unity, gnome

I install Gnome via apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop. After I rebooted, my Unity now look very weird. All icons are replaced by Gnome icons. Is there a way to get my Unity back to normal? I have tried `unity --reset` and `unity --reset-icon` but  they do not work (they freeze). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it's just a misseting in appearance->theme. After the change the theme back to Ambience, it looks all right again.